# Null not allowed, but should be nullable

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have two tables joining with a mapping table. I am getting a null constraint issue though. Below is the error message and the two mappings.  Since both are manyTomany my assumption is that the many could be none,  how can I make it so either product_id or category_id can be null?

Error Message

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCT_OPTION_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into ImageMapping (product_id, image_id) values (?, ?) [23502-168]
```

Categories

```
@JoinTable(
        name = "ImageMapping",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Image> categoryImageId;
```

Products

```
@JoinTable(
        name="ImageMapping",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Image> productImageGroup;
```

Product Options

```
@JoinTable(
        name="ImageMapping",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_option_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Image> productOptionImageGroup;
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another column named `PRODUCT_OPTION_ID` in `ImageMapping` table?

Comment: Yes, the error is about the column `PRODUCT_OPTION_ID` and not about `PRODUCT_ID` or `IMAGE_ID`.

Comment: I just noticed this last night, but the error switches randomly between Product_option_id and Category_id.  I think this is due to the order in which the entities are snapped up as the tables are being generated in H2.    I included the product options join.

Comment: Show us the `CREATE TABLE` for the tables in question.

Comment: You should have a separate join table for each of your associations, instead of rying to use the same one for all.

Comment: @JBNizet, please add that as an answer so I can give you credit.  That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a separate join table for each of your associations instead of trying to use the same one for all.